# Is there an inbuilt animation to switch ccsprites? Like you would with a card in real life

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I've recently started iPhone development, and doing a gameproject.

I have a Piece class that inherits CCSprite, that cointains 2 ccsprites, frontSprite and backsideSprite. 
The idea with this is that when I touch the Piece object, it will do some magic and turn the piece, showing backsideSprite. This in itself is easy, but the **animation** is what I am curious about, and how to make it as easy on me as possible (I'm not that good at designing graphics).

So the question really is, is there a method, inbuilt method in cocos2d etc, that have animations for my wish? That takes this box/rectangle and turns its side? Like you would turn a card in real life.

If it is not an inbuilt method for this, I basically have to go into designmode and make a sequence of pictures that I run right?

Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
id firstAction = [CCOrbitCamera actionWithDuration:1 radius:1 deltaRadius:0 angleZ:0 deltaAngleZ:90 angleX:0 deltaAngleX:0];
id secondAction = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(changeCardImage)];
id thirdAction = [CCOrbitCamera actionWithDuration:1 radius:1 deltaRadius:0 angleZ:270 deltaAngleZ:90 angleX:0 deltaAngleX:0];          

[art1 runAction:[CCSequence actions:firstAction,secondAction,thirdAction,nil]];

-(void)changeCardImage{

      front.texture = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"backSideSprite.png"]; 

}
```